# C++ Named Pipes over network invalid name error

Tags: c++, ipc, named-pipes

I am trying to send messages via named pipes between two Windows pc´s.
When calling `CreateNamedPipe` locally everything works fine. If I change the hostname from `"\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipename"` to `"\\\\myHostname\\pipe\\testpipename"` I get an `ERROR_INVALID_NAME(123)` from `getLastError()`.

This is my code:

```
    BOOL   fConnected = FALSE;
    DWORD  dwThreadId = 0;
    HANDLE hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, hThread = NULL;
    LPTSTR pipeName = /*nullptr*/ TEXT("\\\\myHostname\\pipe\\testpipename");

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { 0 };
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd = { 0 };

    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);

    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);

    sa.bInheritHandle = false;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);

    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
    pipeName,                 // pipe name  
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access 
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe 
    PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode 
    PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode 
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances  
    255,                      // output buffer size 
    255,                      // input buffer size 
    0,                        // client time-out 
    &sa);                     // default security attribute 

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        cout << GetLastError();
        return -2;
    }

    cout << "Waiting for client to connect!" << endl;

    //waiting for client to connect
    fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ?
        TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

    cout << "Client connected! YEAH" << endl;
```

My guess is that the pipename is invalid but I don´t know why. Any Ideas?

Comment: have you tried using the IP address instead of the hostname?

Comment: @user3549596 Yeah, same error occurs.

Comment: might sound silly, but is the pipename correct and is port 445 inbound allowed on the server?

Comment: @user3549596 The firewall is completely turned off on both pc for testing purpose. Do you mean with pipename the complete string or only the hostname part ?

Comment: hmm, why not both?
also this is some very far stretched approach: try setting up client and server with the same username and password (don't forget a password!). then run this stuff.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot even start the server when I put anything else as hostname than the dot. 
Is is correct to put the hostname of the server into the full pipename at the server?
Now I have this:
Server: "\\\\myHostname\\pipe\\testpipename"
Client: "\\\\myHostname\\pipe\\testpipename"

Comment: k, I am not entirely sure, but the `.` is a synonym for localhost. On the server you can leave the dot, on the client change it to the hostname (or IP) of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
Pipenames for Server and Client are:

> Server: `"\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe"`
>   Client:   `"\\\\serverHostName\\pipe\\testpipe"`

Some minor changes at the client were also made.
Full code can be found at [my Github repo](https://github.com/Strizzi12/Drone_Communication/tree/master/IPCComponent).